# htaccess redirect all subfolders/pages on one domain to matching subfolder on new domain (WordPress)

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a bunch of domains that all go to the same site and need to be able to redirect domainalias.com/folder/name to website.com/folder/name.

I currently have the following htaccess which works as far as redirecting the root domain, but as soon as I go into a sub-directory or sub-page, it won't redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress

# Redirect all domains to website.co.uk
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

So to confirm, I want people to be redirected from http://anydomainalias.co.uk/any/sub/folder to http://website.co.uk/any/sub/folder. As it's a WordPress site, I need this to work dynamically. I have 50-odd subdomains so want to avoid having a rule for each one as well (hence the !^website.co.uk rule).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have redirect rule before default WP routing rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all domains to website.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress

</IfModule>
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Sorry, I should re-phrase to pages rather than folders. I need to redirect all pages from the domain aliases to the same page on the main domain. I'll never have a full list of pages as the site is a dynamic WordPress site, so can't make a rule for each one. There are also a good 50 alias domains so I need to stick with the !^website.co.uk rule to handle everything preferably. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! Moving the rule above the WP stuff has done the trick. Thank you :)